# When/How to use permission boundary in serverless function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-serverless, aws-sam

Below SAM template:

```
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.LambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
       MySQSEvent:
        Type: SQS
        Properties:
          Queue: !GetAtt somequeue.Arn
          BatchSize: 10


  somequeue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
```

---

automatically creates default role(JSON) with below policies:

```
{
    "roleName": "somestack-HelloWorldFunctionRole-AAAAAAAAA",
    "policies": [
    {
    "document": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
            "sqs:DeleteMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
          ],
          "Resource": "*"
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole",
    "id": "ANPAJFWJZI6JNND4TSELK",
    "type": "managed",
    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaSQSQueueExecutionRole"
  },
  {
    "document": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
          ],
          "Resource": "*"
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
    "id": "ANPAJNCQGXC42545SKXIK",
    "type": "managed",
    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
  }
],
"trustedEntities": [
  "lambda.amazonaws.com"
]
}
```

---

We need to enforce access rules on specific actions on specific resources(shown below yaml) and deny access to other resources( in log-group ).

1) Do I need to use permission boundary or policy to enforce these below rules? for above SAM template...

```
- Effect: Allow
Action:
  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
Resource:
  - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:*"
```

---

2)

What is the procedure to create [Permission boundary](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction)? through SAM template for Lambda function.. because it asks for ARN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend using permission boundaries in this case. The above mentioned permissions are created by default by SAM. If you need more restrictive permissions then what you can do is to create your own Role and use that Role instead of the one that is automatically created by SAM.

If you use your own Role, SAM will not add additional permissions to it so you can tailor it according to your needs.

Here is an example of how you can do that.

```
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
    ThumbnailFunction:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
            Runtime: nodejs8.10
            Handler: index.handler
            CodeUri: ./src
            Role: !GetAtt FunctionInvokeRole.Arn
            Events:
                MySQSEvent:
                    Type: SQS
                    Properties:
                        Queue: !GetAtt somequeue.Arn
                        BatchSize: 10

    somequeue:
        Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

    FunctionInvokeRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: '2012-10-17'
                Statement:
                    - Effect: 'Allow'
                      Principal:
                          Service:
                              - 'lambda.amazonaws.com'
                      Action:
                          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: 'root'
                  PolicyDocument:
                      Version: '2012-10-17'
                      Statement:
                          - Effect: 'Allow'
                            Action: '*'
                            Resource: '*'
```

Use `Policies` attribute in `FunctionInvokeRole` to specify your own policies.

Comment: **1)** If I create my own role, then, does default role(like `somestack-HelloWorldFunctionRole-AAAAAAAAA`) not automatically get created? **2)** What is the problem with permisssion boundary approach here? rule evaluation logic takes more time... with permission boundary approach?

Comment: That is correct. If you create your own role, default role will not be created. The name will still be similar, in the above case it would be something like `lambda-test-FunctionInvokeRole-RWD8ZEKI8U8T`, but it is the one that you have explicitly defined in your template with your own permissions, not the default one, with default permissions.

Comment: What is the problem with permisssion boundary approach here? are you concerned about rule evaluation logic taking more time... with permission boundary approach?

Comment: No, not really. The problem is that there is no need for using them here. They are more of an advanced feature used when we need to restrict cross account access and for multi account management. Everything that you need in your case, in terms of permissions, can be achieved without setting up boundaries so you would be just complicating things, leaving more room for error.

Comment: yes you are right... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031490/adding-permissionboundary-fails-in-sam-template . any clue on this?

Comment: What is purpose of `AssumeRolePolicyDocument`? with service `lambda.amazonaws.com` and action as `sts:AssumeRole`

Comment: Am getting error: `The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyLambdaRole]. . Rollback requested by user.` after deploy

Comment: `AssumeRolePolicyDocument` is a definition of trust relationship between role and lambda function.

Comment: There is no `MyLambdaRole` in the above template. Are you sure that you did not change it? Because I can deploy the above template without any errors.

Comment: Policyname can be anything other than root?

Comment: Yes but there are restrictions such as length and usage special characters.

Comment: when we say `sts:assumeRole`, which role name does it assume?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Assume role in the above template is just a name of action which belongs to trust policy. You are not calling `sts:AssumeRole` anywhere directly in this case.

Comment: which user creates `FunctionInvokeRole` on Cloudformation stack?

Comment: Again, I am not sure what your goal is with this question because the obvious answer is that the role is created not by a user but by a service which is called, well, CloudFormation and this service creates the role, and every resource in that template, on behalf of the IAM entity (user or role) that is making the CF deploy API call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a policy.
Permission boundaries is an AWS IAM feature which is mainly designed "to delegate permissions management to trusted employees" (i.e. you want to give some users the possibility to create or manage existing AWS users). [1]

As an administrator which configures the system initially, using permissions with statements that contain *Allow* and *Deny* actions should be sufficient to achieve what you want.

**Edit:**

You can restrict the resource to which permission is granted by the following policy for example:

```
- Effect: Deny
Action:
  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
NotResource:
  - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:*"
```

#### References

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/delegate-permission-management-to-developers-using-iam-permissions-boundaries/

Comment: If I add above rules(mentioned in yaml) as policy, then those rules will become subset of existing rules(mentioned in JSON). Isn't it? If I add above rules(in yaml) as `PermissionBoundary` then,  yaml rules intersection JSON rules = yaml rules.. Isn't it?

Comment: If it is all about restricting the resources, then I would suggest, you achieve the intersection by using a Deny action and a NotResource attribute (see edit).